# memcpy into a struct from char array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memcpy

I have a `char buffer[1024]` and a struct

```
typedef struct {
   int record;
   int key;
} leaf_entry;
```

What I am trying to implement is the buffer array acting like a node of a tree that holds many entries of leaf_entry.

If I want to iterate down the buffer to compare an entry in the buffer to another entry

```
for (i = 0; i < max_ents * entry_size; i += entry_size)
{
    leaf_entry curr;
    memcpy (curr, buffer[i], entry_size)
    if (curr == entry_to_compare)
       etc...
}
```

Is this correct? Is there an easier/more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: why are you using a char buffer[] instead of a struct leaf_entry buffer[]?

Comment: why not an array of `leaf_entry`? And why `typedef` a struct?

Comment: char buffer[] because of the spec in my project. We are "loading" a page from disk into 1024-byte main memory. Then in that page, we want to fill it with the entries, which consist of 2 ints.

Comment: In general, you can't just binary dump data into a struct and expect it to work.

Comment: But an example in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/ memcpys from one struct to another. Is that because the source and destination is a same struct?

Comment: @JasonWoo You tagged this as `C++`, and in C++, you can't willy-nilly memcpy structs.  If your struct is `non-POD`, your example produces undefined behavior.  Stick a `std::string` in your struct, and that memcpy becomes a disaster.

Comment: In this case you'll likely get away with it because the structure is nothing but simple datatypes. Don't try that with a structure containing an object or a pointer. Don't try that with an object, either.

Comment: What is the endianness of the ints in the binary data? Is the size of `int` always going to agree with the binary data? Safe way is to create a load function and assemble the ints with bitwise operations.

Comment: Struct is POD. But I see, so this is generally not a good practice. What would you suggest I do instead? I have this char buffer[1024] and it has to hold many entries of 2 ints.

Comment: @JasonWoo Just use `curr = buffer[i]`.  Let the compiler decide to use `memcpy` or not.

Comment: @JasonWoo what does the data look like in the file? Is it a blob of crazy nonsense characters or is it a nice stream of printable numbers?

Comment: What is the endianness of the integers stored in your binary buffer?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if `buffer` is a char buffer then `curr = buffer[i]` is no good

Comment: @JasonWoo cplusplus.com is not a good reference site. That example is naff.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this without copying given that your struct is POD.

I believe something like this should work where offset is the correct byte offset into the char buffer:

```
leaf_entry & x = static_cast<leaf_entry &>(buffer + offset);
```

Comment: and how does he generate this 'offset'?

Comment: Possibility of crash due to data alignment. On a PC or embedded system with a modern processor you'll probably just incur a performance penalty.

Comment: @Nandu offset = n * sizeof(leaf_struct)

Comment: @user4581301 you are correct.  Perhaps, since the buffer contains all ints, it can be aligned correctly to avoid this.

Comment: but that's not how the data was serialized in the page when it was written to disk. He's is reading everything back as bytes. How do you know that is the correct order?

Comment: @AnonMail I am always correct when I am not wrong. A recommendation:  Expand your answer a bit to include calculating the offset and the loop required to prevent overflow.

Comment: @Nandu , you can't know unless you know the protocol used when the file was written. Without the protocol, you are stuck reverse engineering. Assuming your instructor or whoever gave this assignment isn't a jerk, what was written to the file should be sequential and start with record zero at byte zero. After that, the question is what format was the data written in: A binary blob of `leaf_entry`s or was it serialized to a string?

Comment: This violates the strict aliasing rule. `memcpy` would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the approach that standard sorting implementations use - namely, use a user-defined compare function that receives 2 pointers. You then use these pointers to locate the element and from there, access and compare the members you're interested in. This also avoids the unnecessary memory copying.

Consider the following func used to compare ints:

```
int compareIntAsc(const void *int1, const void *int2)
{
    int *num1 = (int*)int1;
    int *num2 = (int*)int2;
    return *num1 - *num2;
}
```

and now consider one which will compare the count member of some structs

```
int compareNodeCountAsc(const void *node1, const void *node1)
{
    return (pHuffmanNode)(node1))->charCount - ((pHuffmanNode)(node2))->charCount;
}
```

If you pass the address of two elements in your array to such a function, you can compare either the record or the key.

e.g  compare element 0 to every other element

**code**

```
typedef struct {
   int record;
   int key;
} leaf_entry, *pLeafEntry;

int compLeafKeyAsc(void *leaf1, void *leaf2)
{
    leaf_entry *p1, *p2;
    p1 = (leaf_entry *)leaf1;
    p2 = (leaf_entry *)leaf2;
    return p1->key - p2->key;
}

void printLeaf(pLeafEntry leaf)
{
    printf("----- leaf -------\n");
    printf("record: %d\n", leaf->record);
    printf("key: %d\n", leaf->key);
}

void demo()
{


    const int nElems = 16;
    leaf_entry leafArray[nElems];
    pLeafEntry firstElement;

    int i;
    for (i=0;i<nElems;i++)
    {
        leafArray[i].record = (rand()%51) + 100;        // record is [100..150]
        leafArray[i].key = (rand()%128);                // key is [0..127]
        printLeaf(&leafArray[i]);
    }

    //e.g  compare element 0 to every other element
    firstElement = &leafArray[0];
    for (i=1; i<nElems; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", firstElement->key );
        int result = compLeafKeyAsc(firstElement, &leafArray[i]);
        if (result < 0)
            printf(" is less than ");
        else if (result > 0)
            printf(" is greater than ");
        else
            printf(" is equal to ");
        printf("%d\n", leafArray[i].key);
    }
}
```

**output**

```
----- leaf -------
record: 141
key: 35
----- leaf -------
record: 110
key: 4
----- leaf -------
record: 144
key: 108
----- leaf -------
record: 103
key: 46
----- leaf -------
record: 134
key: 16
----- leaf -------
record: 144
key: 113
----- leaf -------
record: 125
key: 59
----- leaf -------
record: 116
key: 107
----- leaf -------
record: 137
key: 38
----- leaf -------
record: 133
key: 60
----- leaf -------
record: 106
key: 12
----- leaf -------
record: 126
key: 25
----- leaf -------
record: 137
key: 94
----- leaf -------
record: 130
key: 28
----- leaf -------
record: 132
key: 55
----- leaf -------
record: 141
key: 94
35 is greater than 4
35 is less than 108
35 is less than 46
35 is greater than 16
35 is less than 113
35 is less than 59
35 is less than 107
35 is less than 38
35 is less than 60
35 is greater than 12
35 is greater than 25
35 is less than 94
35 is greater than 28
35 is less than 55
35 is less than 94
```

Comment: Do not use C-style casts. Use `static_cast`. If that doesn't compile, think again about what you are doing.

Comment: Good catch, Been writing a lot of assembly lately.